# how can you create an artificial cursor line?

Tags: java, javafx, keyboard, cursor

I need my fake cursor to always be visible with the text field even when it moves without resizing anything. But I don't know how to do that. the "¦" is essentially supposed to act as the blinking curser line whenever your typing. But I don't know how if that can even be added with a non editable text field.

is there a way to move the view of the "¦" to act as an artificial cursor?

or is there a better way to handle my problem?

This is a VERY watered down version of what I have so far.

```
public class fake extends Application
{

    TextField equationText=new TextField("¦sadfhoiqehre  jnvlsvkslurgbqo938y28374 9whfo37282736kabviouah7y82");

    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        equationText.setEditable(false);
        equationText.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
        equationText.setFocusTraversable(false);
        equationText.setDisable(true);
        equationText.setOpacity(1);     //make text not look disabled
        equationText.setStyle("-fx-border-color:black");
        equationText.setPrefSize(360,30);

        VBox pane=new VBox();
        pane.getChildren().add(equationText);

        Scene scene=new Scene(pane);
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(event -> keyboardControls(event));

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Calculator FX");
        primaryStage.show();

    }


    void moveIndex(char c)
    {
        if(c=='z')
        {
            //left
            String pieThing=equationText.getText();
            System.out.println("Ding\t\t\t"+pieThing);
            System.out.println("Size of string "+pieThing.length());
            System.out.println("index of thing "+pieThing.indexOf("¦"));

            if(pieThing.indexOf("¦")>0)
            {
                int i=pieThing.indexOf("¦");
                pieThing=pieThing.replace("¦","");
                StringBuilder pieThingBuilder=new StringBuilder(pieThing);
                pieThingBuilder.insert(i-1,"¦");
                pieThing=pieThingBuilder.toString();
                System.out.println("Done with right "+pieThing);
                equationText.setText(pieThing);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("left failed");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //right
            String pieThing=equationText.getText();
            System.out.println("Ding\t\t\t"+pieThing);
            System.out.println("Size of string "+pieThing.length());
            System.out.println("index of thing "+pieThing.indexOf("¦"));

            if(pieThing.indexOf("¦")+1!=pieThing.length())
            {
                int i=pieThing.indexOf("¦");
                pieThing=pieThing.replace("¦","");
                StringBuilder pieThingBuilder=new StringBuilder(pieThing);
                pieThingBuilder.insert(i+1,"¦");
                pieThing=pieThingBuilder.toString();
                System.out.println("Done with right "+pieThing);
                equationText.setText(pieThing);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("right failed");
            }

        }
    }
    void keyboardControls(javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent key)
    {

        if(key.getCode()==KeyCode.Z)
            moveIndex('z');
        else if(key.getCode()==KeyCode.X)
            moveIndex('x');
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
```

Comment: Rather than inserting the fake cursor into the text itself, you could instead draw your fake cursor to a glass pane over top of the TextField, or you could do custom painting on the TextField to show the cursor. If you want to stick with what you have, then add a timer of some sort to change the cursor symbol to give it the "blinking" effect

Comment: you still didn't explain what you _really_ want to achieve - why/in which context _exactly_ do you want the caret (== the visual hint as to where a character will we inserted) to be visible for a not-editable textField? Why not make it editable? BTW: _it moves without resizing anything_ doesn't make much sense to me, nothing in a textField is resized when editable, so what do you mean?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you want that this code isn't already doing.

Comment: @kleopatra if you run the code you will see that the text in the text field is too large to display, and if you move the fake curser to the far right the text field wont follow along. I am asking how this can be fixed so that the text field displays the text followed by the fake curser. Like when you use a real curser.

Comment: repeating: learn and use the technical vocabulary, best including its spelling (cursor != caret) - and given that rather unusual requirement explain WHY you want WHAT exactly. Sounds like you are barking at the wrong tree (or technically speaking, like a xy-problem). And edit the question to add clarifications (vs. hiding them in comments), while you are at it fix the violation of naming conventions.

Comment: @kleopatra this is a watered down version of my code. The original is very large. This is a calculator that will be somewhat similar to the Microsoft calculator. Except with a "caret" to help edit values. but it doesn't work well if the text field cant follow along with the "caret"

Comment: I haven't used it much, so this could be totally wrong. I would suggest you look into `TextFormatter`. My guess is that you can use it to place the symbol `¦` in the proper location depending on which key is pressed.  I repeat this is just a guess. I haven't used `TextFormatter` much, and when I have, the cases have been pretty straightforward.

Comment: @Sedrick I actually have something that moves the `¦` Symbol using `stringBuilder` but the problem is when i move it too far in any direction the text field wont shift view to keep following it

Comment: My guess is make your `TextField` long enough to hold a good amount of data. Use a `TextFormatter` to not allow the number of characters to exceed the with of the `TextField`. Other option is to use a multiline `TextField` or `TextArea`.

Comment: @kleopatra could you be a bit more specific please? I don't see what's wrong with the names besides them being irrelevant

Comment: you did search for "java naming conventions" and read what you found, didn't you? Then compare each rule with your code :) hint: look at your class name

Answer (score -1):

I have found the answer. No one actually told me about that the "caret" position can be moved with code. So after like a week of looking around i have found that i can just do `equationText.positionCaret(i+1);` after changing `i` to have the updated index. And its the same bit of code for each movement. Unfortunatly this dosent act like an actual curser line would, and only sticks to the far right